# mp4parse on Android error - MovieCreator.build() : "java.lang.RuntimeException: No box object found for ftyp"

Tags: mp4parser

i'm using [mp4parser](https://github.com/JamesPrudente/mp4parser-android-library) lib. Error at `MovieCreator.build(new FileInputStream(f1).getChannel())` with exception : `RuntimeException: No box object found for ftyp` . Plz help me!

Comment: Are you using an official build or do you compile your own version? It looks to me that you might be missing the aspectJ stuff